# Приложение python на cpanel

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpanel

Прошу подсказать, как можно решить вопрос на хостинге с Cpanel, что бы настроить приложение на Python. Нашёл в сети только как настроить приложения с flask или django.
Но если код не велик, задача очень прозаичная, то можно ли как то обойтись без этих фреймворков и как то настроить cpanel на исполнение файлов PY? Ведь на локальном компе можно создать файл с кодом, собственно он и будет сервером локальным:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

и файлы PY начинают исполняться, конечно, и html при этом тоже транслируется.

Понятное дело на хостинге Apache. Надо их как то подружить.

Напомню, для настройки приложения Python  в Cpanel используется следующие параметры в форме:

[image: форма настройки приложения]

Вот такая задачка. Заранее благодарен любым советам.
Просьба не советовать использовать flask или django.

Comment: Конечно можно было бы попробовать поэкспериментировать, но чтобы понять, какой формат почтового индекса этому хостингу нужен при регистрации, похоже придется брутфорс применить.

Comment: @insolor ну... не уверен что нужно так то уж радикально. :)  там всё проще, с индексами, почтовыми, на мой взгляд. Вы точно здесь пробовали?  https://cpanelhosting.ru/free/

Comment: Нет, я на https://cpanel.net набрел)